# Nmap Changed My Network?

Tags: networking, fedora, nmap

I am running a clean install of Fedora 24, and I am not sure if I accidentally did some weird key combo, but I entered:

`nmap -sT -Pn [IPaddress]`

and, for some reason, this added a PCI network to my PC, switched to it, and did not allow me to require my usual eth0.

I restarted my PC, and am fine, now.

But what would have caused this network change?

Comment: If you want, I can explain what you've exactly done by `nmap -sT -Pn target` command, but the change is not caused by nmap. By default Nmap has nothing to do with your interfaces unless you want it to.

Comment: @FarazX An explination/speculation would be nice!

Comment: Alright, here you are, I just posted an answer. I did some test for making sure, I checked the command on MacOS X, CentOS, Kali Linux, and it didn't change anything related to interfaces. So ... I think the problem should be something else. Nmap, is a powerful tool, I recommend you read its full manual page plus the book I've added in my answer.

Comment: BTW, PCI (Peripheral Component Interconnect) is an industry specification for connecting hardware devices to a computer's central processor. So as we can guess both Ethernet and Wi-Fi network adapters for desktop and notebook computers commonly utilize PCI. So if you think there is any special problem occurring on your system related to interfaces or etc., you can post a question with all details, so we'll be able to help you more precisely. But for this question, no Nmap is not a problem-maker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK by default Nmap has nothing to do with your network interfaces unless you want it to. I recommend you read Gordon (Fyodor) Lyon's [NMAP NETWORK SCANNING](https://nmap.org/book/) book.

For instance if you want to use a different network interface, you should pass `-e` option followed by required interface name, e.g. `-e wlan0`. So I don't think it can be caused by Nmap.

What you have used is including `-sT` and `-Pn` options:

### -sT (TCP connect scan)

As we can see in both Nmap manual page and the book I just recommended, TCP connect scan is the default TCP scan type when SYN scan is not an option. This is the case when a user does not have raw packet privileges or is scanning IPv6 networks. Instead of writing raw packets as most other scan types do, Nmap asks the underlying operating system to establish a connection with the target machine and port by issuing the `connect` system call.

This is the same high-level system call that web browsers, P2P clients, and most other network-enabled applications use to establish a connection. Rather than read raw packet responses off the wire, Nmap uses this API to obtain status information on each connection attempt.

Note that this type of scan, and the FTP bounce scan (-b) are the only scan types available to **unprivileged users**.

Note that it is not a stealth scan.

### -Pn (Ping-less Scan)

In previous versions of Nmap, -Pn was -P0, and -PN.

This option disables ping scan and skips the Nmap discovery stage.

There are many reasons for disabling ping, for instance intrusive vulnerability assessment, and it can be used to bypass when a host is protected by firewall.

**CONCLUSION**: It shouldn't have been caused by Nmap, at least not by this command you have used.

**N.B.** BTW, PCI (Peripheral Component Interconnect) is an industry specification for connecting hardware devices to a computer's central processor. So as we can guess both Ethernet and Wi-Fi network adapters for desktop and notebook computers commonly utilize PCI.